# In R: Trying to determine origin location of repeating ID numbers in a data set

Tags: r, reshape

Thank you in advance for taking the time to read this. I have just started learning R with no programming background, so even if you can help me put a name to the analysis or function I'm trying to perform so that I can effectively look for other resources it would be GREATLY appreciated:

I am trying to see if animals that were released from specific sites have moved outside of their release locations. I have 4 release sites and over 20 transects within the sites. The "RECAP1" represents a unique ID number captured at a transect that corresponds to a specific origin release site and the "RUW" and "RLW" are a couple of the origin release sites.

below I have provided a sample of the set I'm using, I used an ID # in the first row of "RECAP1" that matches the number in the last row of "RUW" (my first time using the dput() function, so apologies if I flailed miserably):

```
structure(list(RUW = structure(c(4L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 6L), .Label = c("3D9.1C2DB5FC90", 
"3D9.1C2DB62A80", "3D9.1C2DB66C91", "3D9.1C2DB67255", "3D9.1C2DB67A27", 
"3D9.1C2DBF8F56"), class = "factor"), RLW = structure(c(3L, 4L, 
6L, 1L, 2L, 5L), .Label = c("3D9.1C2D859450", "3D9.1C2DBAA68F", 
"3D9.1C2DBE338A", "3D9.1C2DBE7B85", "3D9.1C2DBF15B8", "3D9.1C2DBF756E"
), class = "factor"), RECAP1 = structure(c(4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("", "3D9.1C2DB5FF58", "3D9.1C2DB61CDC", "3D9.1C2DBF8F56"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("RUW", "RLW", "RECAP1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

What I would like to achieve is a tabulated/list output that tells me what column (by name) the repeated ID number originated from.

This is an example of what kind of output I am looking for:

```
         DETECTION          RECAP SITE         ORIGIN SITE
1   3D9.1C2DBF8F56     RECAP1             RUW
2   3D9.1C2DBF33H4     RECAP17            RLW
3   3D9.1C2DF4BE93     RECAP6             RLM
```

Comment: Your `recap site` column values looks different from the `RECAP1` column. Is that only for example purposes or am I missing something?

Comment: Oh no, sorry, you're not missing anything, I only did the 2nd and 3rd rows as examples. I have about 20 "RECAPx" sites with over 600 detections, I just wasn't sure how much data you guys would want to see.

Comment: What exactly does each row represent?  I don't really understand the ID variable here.

Comment: @iShouldUseAName , in the example output: the rows contain an identification code that was detected and is unique to one animal that was released from a specific location. The other values refer to the raw data and are the column names from the recapture locations and original release locations.  In the raw data sample I provided: all values are the ID codes,the first two columns are release sites, third column is where the animal was recaptured

Comment: Thanks for sharing reproducible input. Please make sure the sample output is also achievable with your reproducible input. In this case, the values don't match at all, so it makes it tough to guess at what you're trying to do.

Comment: In your sample data, you only have one 'RECAP' site, RECAP1. Shall we guess that other RECAP sites, such as 17 and 6, appear as separate columns in your data?

Comment: @Henrik yes, sorry for the confusion, that output is not actually from my workspace, I typed it in manually for this forum

Comment: Please read [**this**](http://sscce.org/) for some general ideas on minimal reproducible examples.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're trying to do. Basically, for each `RECAP1` value, you want to find out if it occurs in `RUW` or `RLW`?

```
library(reshape2)
df2 <- melt(
  df, 
  id.vars = 'RECAP1'
  )
df2[df2$RECAP1 %in% df2$value,1:2]
```

Output -

```
> df2[df2$RECAP1 %in% df2$value,1:2]
          RECAP1 variable
1 3D9.1C2DBF8F56      RUW
7 3D9.1C2DBF8F56      RLW
```

If I misunderstood, can you please connect your sample input and sample output with the exact process you're trying to accomplish?